# how to get object id and application id of kubernetes service principal azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-aks

is their a way to get Object id and application id of Azure Kubernetes service

Note* service principal of kubernetes service is not in Active directory it was generated with AKS only
and it Acrpull role is assigned to ACR Container Registries

Comment: When you said "..service principal of kubernetes service is not in Active directory it was generated with AKS only", do you mean [AKS-managed Azure Active Directory integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/aks/managed-aad)?

Comment: Or is it [managed identities in Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/aks/use-managed-identity)?

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT no aks is not managed AD or it not an managed identities

Comment: Then can you clarify the statement?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misunderstanding of service principal of Azure Kubernetes Service.

The service principal is exactly the managed identity of Azure Kubernetes Service.

When you create an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster, you need to configure the Authentication method for it. Here I choose "System-assigned managed identity".

[image]

After that, you can find it in **Azure AD** -> **Enterprise applications** -> **All applications** (just search for the name of Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster). But It's unavailable in **Azure AD** -> **Application registrations**.

Another quick method is to use Azure CLI. Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity#create-an-aks-cluster-with-managed-identities).

Create an AKS cluster:

```
az aks create -g myResourceGroup -n myManagedCluster --enable-managed-identity
```

And then use the following command to query objectid of your control plane managed identity:

```
az aks show -g myResourceGroup -n myManagedCluster --query "identity"
```

Besides, if you try to assign a role to ACR Container Registries with this service principal in Azure portal, it's unnecessary to enter the object id. Enter the name of the AKS cluster is enough.